# SyntaxHighlighter doesn't show html code properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, syntaxhighlighter

In my project I'm using SyntaxHighlighter jQuery plugin for displaying code samples.
I really like it, but I got a problem.
When I need to display a code example, which contains HTML, plugin doesn't work correctly.

I add all the scripts and stylesheets I need:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="syntax/styles/shCoreEclipse.css"/>
    <script src="syntax/scripts/shCore.js"></script>
    <script src="syntax/scripts/shBrushPhp.js"></script>
    <script src="syntax/scripts/shBrushXml.js"></script>
```

Then I have my pre tag:

```
<pre class="brush: php; toolbar: false; html-script: true;">
    <html>
        <body>
            <div style="font-weight: bold"><?= str_replace("\n", "<br/>", $var) ?></div>
            <?
                /***********************************
                ** Multiline block comments
                **********************************/

                $stringWithUrl = "http://alexgorbatchev.com";
                $stringWithUrl = 'http://alexgorbatchev.com';

                ob_start("parseOutputBuffer");      // Start Code Buffering
                session_start();
            ?>
        </body>
    </html>
</pre>
```

And the output I get is:

```
<div style="font-weight: bold"><!--?= str_replace("\n", "<br/-->", $var) ?></div>
<!--?
    /***********************************
    ** Multiline block comments
    **********************************/

    $stringWithUrl = "http://alexgorbatchev.com";
    $stringWithUrl = 'http://alexgorbatchev.com';

    ob_start("parseOutputBuffer");      // Start Code Buffering
    session_start();
?-->
```

Highlighter deletes my html and body tags.
I am doing everything like in documentation: http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/demo/html-script.html

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Encode the content of your `pre` element properly – that means first of all exchanging `<` for `&lt;` and  `>` for `&gt;`

Answer (score 0):

Add this Js file **xregexp-min.js** (download from [here](http://xregexp.com/v/3.0.0/xregexp-min.js)) and also add following script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        SyntaxHighlighter.config.bloggerMode = true;
        SyntaxHighlighter.defaults['smart-tabs'] = false;
        SyntaxHighlighter.all();
</script>
```

May be help you

Comment: `bloggerMode = true` is only for  hosting on blogger.com?

Comment: `smart-tabs: false` doesn't work, even in the officer demo, ['smart-tabs' demo](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/demo/smart-tabs.html).